# What is the name for the bar on a site appearing above or below the navigation bar, usually containing a discount or other promotion?

Tags: interface-design, terminology

What is the name for the bar on a site appearing above or below the navigation bar, usually containing a discount or other promotion? Here are a few examples of what I'm talking about:

## Nike

[image]

## Adidas

[image]

## Brooks

[image]

And so on, you get the idea. Does it have a recognizable standard name, like how everyone knows what I'm talking about when I say "navigation bar"?

- Promotion bar?
- Slogan bar?
- Tagline bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of this component can be divided into two groups.

1. The first is the common name of such bars.
   It can be:

- **Message Bar**
  Message bars are non-modal semantic dialogs that can be displayed at the top of the page or contextually within a task flow.
- **Notification Bar**
  A website notification bar is most commonly placed at the top or bottom of the screen to draw visitors’ attention to a specific update or message.

2. The second is the name of the component that can be used to create this bar.
   It all depends on the choice of the creator of this component. In different design systems, they can be used in different ways, but they still have common principles.
   Of these, it may be:

- **Alert message**
  Generally, an alert displays a prominent message at the top of the screen. It could be used to promote a new feature or provide action-based feedback messages. They’re persistent and nonmodal, allowing the user to either ignore them or interact with them at any time

*Very recommend this article for you*
https://www.leadpages.com/blog/alert-bar-examples

[image]
[image]
[image]

- **Snackbars**
  Dismissive snackbars appear temporarily, and disappear on their own without requiring user input.  Non-dismissive snackbars persist until the user takes an action or selects the close affordance.
  https://m3.material.io/components/snackbar/overview

[image]

- **Toast**
  The toast component is used to give feedback to users after an action has taken place.
  https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/toast
  [image]

**Summary:**
As you can see, there are dozens of variations of these bars and components. It all depends on your choice and the terminology that you have defined for yourself. Do not be afraid to assign them the parameters that you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would call these "notification banners". They often but don't always have a call to action. Searching "notification banner web design" comes up with a lot of similar items.

Answer (score -1):

I would call it a Top Bar Call to Action. It may go by a different term but you will find plenty of information about this if you searched "Top Bar Call to Action". It's the first thing you want your visitor to see when they open the site. It's designed to provoke an immediate response, usually using an imperative verb such as "call now", "find out more" or "visit a store today".

This is similar to a modal popup call to action without being as intrusive.